# Makefile Lib linking issue

Tags: c++, makefile, static-libraries

In my project I have 3 folder :

- Includes which contain lib Header files
- Libs which contain lib files
- Sources which contain my project sources files

but when I'm trying to compile I get these error :

```
g++ -W -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic -L ./Libs/ -langelscript -I./Includes/ -o Pretorian Sources/math.o Sources/main.o Sources/functions.o 
Sources/main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `asCreateScriptEngine'
Sources/main.o: In function `ConfigureEngine(asIScriptEngine*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `asGetLibraryOptions'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my Makefile :

```
NAME = Pretorian

SRCDIR = ./Sources/
HDDIR = ./Includes/
LIBDIR = ./Libs/

SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)*.cpp)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

CC = g++

RM = rm -f
ECHO = echo -e

CFLAGS += -W -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic
HFLAGS = -I$(HDDIR)
LDFLAGS = -L $(LIBDIR) -langelscript

all: $(NAME)

%.o: %.cpp
                $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(HFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
                        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(HFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $^
                @$(ECHO) '\033[0;32m> Compiled Without error\033[0m'

clean:
                $(RM) $(OBJS)
                @$(ECHO) '\033[0;33m> Directory cleaned\033[0m'

fclean: clean
                $(RM) $(NAME)
                @$(ECHO) '\033[0;33m> Remove executable\033[0m'

re: fclean all

SRCList:
        @$(ECHO) $(SRCS)

OBJList:
        @$(ECHO) $(OBJS)
```

I have the correct include in Includes folder and I have the libangelscript.a in the Libs folder

Comment: To me it seems that you aren't linking the static lib, but a dynamic one. Can you try `g++ ... ./Libs/libangelscript.a` without the -langelscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an order problem

I put my LDFLAG before the file :
I replace this : `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(HFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $^`
by this : `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(HFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $^ $(LDFLAGS)`